# Command line printing of text files to fit one page on Unix / Mac OS

Tags: macos, unix, printing, cups, lpr

I need to print a bunch of text files. They are all pretty small and they fit okay on one text page if the font size is chosen adequately. How can I do this automatically?

I tried (find ... `-exec` ... for the full call, this is one document only )

```
lp o fit-to-page -o media=A4 text.txt
```

but this just prints text.txt on one page of A4.

```
lp -o cpi=16 -o lpi=12 -o media=A4 text.txt
```

does the job, but how do I "auto-detect" cpi and lpi?

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet does the job for me

```
#!/bin/sh
# 8,2677 x 11,6929 inch = A4
awk ' { if ( length > L ) { L=length} }END{ print L}' "$1" > width
awk ' { print NR } ' "$1" | tail -1 > height
cpiraw=`cat width`
echo "$cpiraw"
lpiraw=`cat height`
echo "$lpiraw"
cpi=$(((cpiraw/8+1)))
echo "$cpi"
lpi=$(((lpiraw/11+1)))
echo "$lpi"
lp -o cpi=$cpi -o lpi=$lpi -o media=A4 "$1"
rm width
rm height
```

I'm by no means a unix shell expert and I'd be grateful if someone came up with a 'proper' answer